# No output to screen

Tags: php, html

If I make a standalone script, it works. (example www.mywebserver.com/test.php).
when it is embed it in a html file, I get no output, and calling it remotely does not work either.
please help this beginner figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>PHP! </title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo "test";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how is it *embeded* ?

Comment: *"when it is embed it in a html file, I get no output"* in `.html`????? if so, you have to instruct Apache to treat those AS PHP. Yeah, that's gotta be it. Closed "as per" dupe.

Comment: What do you mean by "embed it in an HTML file"?  If you file's extension really is `.html` then your web server won't process PHP code in it by default.  The extension should be `.php`.

Comment: Thank you! I got it now!